# How adapt an image into a geometric figure in html and css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello stackoverflow friends.

My is I made a geometric figure in many divs because am do a crazy website but i don't know how adapt the image into those divs because my image doesn't take the original width and you look at in a test html file how this damage the appearance please help me. This is the code here.

```
<div id="slider-container">
    <div id="container-child">
        <div class="css-shapes-preview" id="first-interfell-slide" /*style="background-image: url(images/_web-slider_back01.jpg); height: 75vh;"*/ >

            <img class="image-slider" src="images/_web-slider_back01.jpg" alt="first-main--slider-1">
        </div>
        <div class="css-shapes-preview" id="second--slide" /*style="background-image: url(images/_web-slider_back02.jpg); height: 75vh;"*/ >
            <img class="image-slider" src="images/_web-slider_back02.jpg" alt="first-main--slider-2">
        </div>
        <div class="css-shapes-preview" id="third--slide" /*style="background-image: url(images/_web-slider_back03.jpg); height: 75vh;"* >
            <img class="image-slider" src="images/_web-slider_back03.jpg" alt="first-main--slider-3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the css file is:

```
    #slider-container{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 350vw;
    display: block;
    min-width: 1200px;
    margin-left: -3em;
}
#container-child{
    width: 110vw;
    margin-left: -5rem;
}
.css-shapes-preview{ 
    position: relative;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 0px; 
    transform: translateX(-60px) rotate(0deg) skew(350deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-60px) rotate(0deg) skew(350deg);
    float: left;
}
.slider-imgs-parttern{
    width: 50%;
}
.image-slider{
    height: 70vh;
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

The reason is because i want to do a slider with the three images.

Comment: Could you please provide a codepen link?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#length-percentage 

https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in this two pages:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

and

http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/